# merge values in mysql and sort

Tags: mysql, sorting

I a mysql table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE vote (

    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `site` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `nr` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '1',
    `time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

The same user can have many entries. I want to sort by highest `nr`, but since the same `username`can have many entries with different `nr`. Same `username` entries must merge and the `nr` values must be added together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
select username, sum(nr) as nrSum
 from vote
 group by username
 order by nrSum desc
```